# Logical OR: the second operand is not evaluated (6.5.14.4), but the compiler generates warning: violation of the standard?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, warnings, logical-operators, logical-or

ISO/IEC 9899:202x (E) working draft — February 5, 2020 C17..C2x N2479:

> 6.5.14 Logical OR operator:
>
> 4. If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated.

Context: There is one C compiler, which generates warning `condition is always true / false` for expressions involving logical operators. For example, if in expression `a || b` variable `b` is `unequal to 0`, then the compiler generates `condition is always true` (mentioning the position of `b` in the source code).

Question: Can the fact of generation of such a warnings be interpreted as a violation of `6.5.14.4`? Please, provide explanation / argumentation / references.

Note: `gcc / clang / cl` (configured with the highest warning level) does not generate any warnings for the example above.

UPD. MRE:

```
int main(void)
{
    int c1 = 1, c2 = 1, r = 0;
    if ( c1 || c2 ) { r = 1; }
    return r;
}
$ cc x.c
x.c:4:10: warning: condition is always true
x.c:4:16: warning: condition is always true
```

Comment: Please show [mcve] demonstrating the warning. But in general, it is the static analyzer who is generating it, and not the runtime. So no, it cannot be interpreted as standard violation.

Comment: Compilers are allowed to tell you about things that, while legal, may not be what you intend. A common case is an assignment in an if statement (`if (x = 3)`), which while perfectly legal, is often not what the programmer intended.

Comment: Compiler warning is not an observable effect of evaluation.

Comment: 5.1.1.3 note 9: *"The intent is that an implementation should identify the nature of, and where possible localize, each violation. Of course, an implementation is **free to produce any number of diagnostics** as long as a valid program is still correctly translated. It may also successfully translate an invalid program."* Emphasis added.

Comment: Which compiler on which platform produces those warnings?  The compiler is not wrong — both terms of the condition are always true.  It doesn't matter whether it evaluates them or not.  It may reduce the code to `int main(void) { return 1; }` — it likely will if there's any optimization at all.

Comment: You should not cite paragraphs with a period separator the same as the clauses because  this fails to distinguish some clauses and paragraphs, such as clause 6.5.1 and clause 6.5 paragraph 1.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer (and others): Whether the compiler may issue a diagnostic or not is not the issue *per se*. The issue is that, in order to decide whether to issue such a warning, the compiler must try to evaluate the second operand and, if the warning is to be issued, to have succeeded (and determined it was 1), yet 6.5.14 4 prohibits evaluating the second operand (unless the first is zero).

Comment: @EricPostpischil _The issue is that, in order to decide whether to issue such a warning, the compiler must try to evaluate the second operand_ If a compiler produces an error for `int main(void) { return 0 || x; }`, does it mean it evaluates the second operand?

Comment: Just curious: is there a warning if you change `c1 = 1` to `c1 = 0`? BTW which C compiler do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While one might argue the only way the compiler could have known the value of the second operand of `||` was to have evaluated it, and this violates the prohibition on evaluation in C 2018 6.5.14 4 (“… If the first operand of an `||` compares unequal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated”) if the first operand compares unequal to 0, it is understood that “evaluation” refers to evaluations made during program execution, not translation. The C conceptual models described in C 2018 5.1 separate translation and execution. 6.5.14 4 is a prohibition on evaluation during program execution, not during translation.